# Wget Pattern Problem

Tags: linux, download, wget

I am having a problem with wget and accept patterns.

What I want to do is only download files which match the pattern

```
\*/images/src/test\*.jpg.
```

I am using the command

```
wget -r -A "\*/images/src/test\*.jpg" domain.com
```

For some reason the pattern will not work with slashes in it.

`\*test\*.jpg` works great, but as soon as there's a forward slash in there it fails!
I know `wget` uses the shell's pattern matching, but slashes should work, somehow they do not though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the accept/reject patterns specified with the `-A`/`-R` switches are only matched against the filename portion of the URL, in other words the part after the last slash. The info documentation describes it as follows:

```
Finally, it's worth noting that the accept/reject lists are matched
twice against downloaded files: once against the URL's filename
portion, to determine if the file should be downloaded in the first
place; then, after it has been accepted and successfully downloaded,
the local file's name is also checked against the accept/reject lists
to see if it should be removed.
```

There are separate switches (`-I`/`-X`) which specify patterns to match against the directory part of the URL but as far as I can see there is nothing which matches against the whole path including both the directory and the filename.